# liferay: resourceLocalService.addResources() is not adding resources to liferay resourcepermission table

Tags: java, mysql, liferay-6

I am performing CRUD operaions of an employee  where i am trying to add employee to emp table created through service builder..I am setting permissions through model resource.

Below is my add emp code :

```
public void addEmp(long groupId, long companyId, long userId,
            String empName, String loc) throws PortalException, SystemException {

        Date now = new Date();
        long empId = CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment(Emp.class.getName());

        Emp emp = empPersistence.create(empId);

        emp.setGroupId(groupId);
        emp.setCompanyId(companyId);
        emp.setCreateDate(now);
        emp.setEmpName(empName);
        emp.setLocation(loc);


         EmpUtil.update(emp, false);

        resourceLocalService.addResources(companyId, groupId, userId,
                Emp.class.getName(), empId, false, true, true);


    }
```

Through this code i am able to add employee to my emp table but resources are not getting added to my resourcepermissions table through this code..

```
resourceLocalService.addResources(companyId, groupId, userId,
                    Emp.class.getName(), empId, false, true, true);
```

And also when I look into resourceactions table there also I could not find the basic action ids  entries like `ADD_TO_PAGE, VIEW, PERMISSIONS, CONFIGURATION` of this class..

I am unable to find out what could be the problem..
Any help please?

Comment: Have you created default.xml with model resource actions defined? and giving path of that xml in portlet.properties

Answer (score 1):

How ***Pankaj Kathiriya*** tells in his comment you must define default permission for your portlet.

After that Liferay will create **Resource** (your portlet, your Employe model, ...) and **ResourceAction** (DELETE, VIEW, ...)

After that you can use code like this

```
ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil.addResourcePermission(companyId, resourceName, scope, primKeyId, roleId, actionKey);
```

where

- **companyId** is a long corresponding to your companyId (use PortalUtil.getCompanyId() or PortalUtil.getDefaultCompanyId() to get it)
- **resourceName** is a String (in you case Emp.class.getname())
- **scope** is the scope of your permission (look at ResourceConstants.SCOPE_* to see availabl values)
- **primKeyId** the primary key of your resource (in your case emp.getEmpId())
- **roleId** the id of the role for which you want to define the permission
- **actionKey** is the name of the action (in your case you have to define values in default.xml else you can take a look at ActionKeys)

Answer (score 0):

I think that as your are working in the portlet layer (in your portlet class), calling Liferay services directly might not work: please try calling Liferay's static Utils classes instead.

something like this

```
 resourceLocalServiceUtil.addResources(companyId, groupId, userId,
                Emp.class.getName(), empId, false, true, true);
```